# When will the 64bit eWasm EVM be launched?

Tags: evm, eth-2.0, rust, wasm

Now with the eth2.0 delay, I can't find out when eWASM will be fully adopted. For some strange reason, [the single most important question about eWASM is missing from their FAQ](https://ewasm.readthedocs.io/en/mkdocs/faq/) and this change doesn't appear to be in the [grey glacier announcement](https://blog.ethereum.org/2022/06/16/gray-glacier-announcement/).

I read that this change would move from the 256bit machine to a more reasonable 64bit architecture.  So when is this change supposed to take place?